# Passing a javascript array through HTML form to another js file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, associative-array

I have this javascript code in my html.

```
answers.push({
    answer:$('#answer_1').val(),
    correctAnswer:$('#choice_1').is(":checked")
});
questions.push({
    questionNumber:1,
    questionType:questionType, 
    questionText:questionText,
    answers:answers
}); 
$('.hiddenField').val(JSON.stringify(questions));
```

So as you could see, I have the answers array inside the questions array. I want to pass this questions array to a server side javascript file. I m trying to do that in HTML form's POST method using a hidden input as below.

```
<form action="/new" method="POST">
<div class = "quiz_basic">
<input type = "hidden" class = "hiddenField" name = "questions" />
</div> </form>
```

In the server side js file, when i try to access it using the req.body.questions param, I m getting "unexpected token u" error. This is my server side code. I m using nodejs framework.

```
    router.post('/new', function(req, res, next){
    var questions = JSON.parse(req.body.questions);
    console.log('Question array is ', questions);
    var answers = JSON.parse(req.body.questions.answers);
    console.log('Answer array is ', answers);
  res.send('success');
}
```

If I remove the answers array object from the questions array and pass only that via HTML POST method, I m able to parse it without any problem. How should I send an array which holds another array as one of its elements as one object via HTML? Can you guys help me out please?

questions.json looks like this

```
[{"questionNumber":1,"questionType":"radio","questionText":"Whats your name","answers":[{"answer":"Peter","correctAnswer":true},{"answer":"Dave","correctAnswer":false},{"answer":"Adam","correctAnswer":false},{"answer":"Steve","correctAnswer":false}]}]
```

As I said above, if I remove the "answers" array and send it, it doesn't throw an error on server side.

Thanks

Comment: Please fix your HMTL formatting: `... <div class="quiz_basic"><input type="hidden" class="hiddenField" name="questions" /> ...`

Comment: Can you write the complete error stack trace?

Comment: You can submit to the server JS arrays and objects by AJAX (XmlHttpRequest). There are many handy wrappers for it e.g. in jQuery.

Comment: Can you post, on how does questions json looks like?

Comment: Edited my post with more details. Added the questions.json, formatted html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have valid JSON string, when you parse it  `var questions = JSON.parse(req.body.questions);` you get `Array` of objects - we are good so far (there is no problem with nested `Array`).

1st problem begins when you try to parse `var answers = JSON.parse(req.body.questions.answers);`. `req.body.questions` is a `String` at this point, and property `.answers` can not be accessed. SOLUTION: don't parse second time, lets use `var questions` which is already parsed.

2nd problem is that `.answers` does not belong to `var answers` since it is an `Array`. It is property of array **elements**. SOLUTION: lets take first array element `var answers = questions[0].answers;`

Try to do this:

```
router.post('/new', function(req, res, next){
    var questions = JSON.parse(req.body.questions);
    console.log('Question array is ', questions);
    var answers = questions[0].answers;
    console.log('Answer array is ', answers);
  res.send('success');
}
```

This fixes parsing problem, but not sure that initial JSON structure is correct.. What if there are multiple questions in 'questions' array, are you going to post them all in once? If yes, than some sort of looping should be involved, in order to access right answers (`var answers = questions[0].answers` => `questions[i].answers`)

Comment: Yes sir. Thank you so much. You are right about my json. I would have more than one question and all would be submitted at once. I m using Mongo db to save those and I m looping through the questions array length and able to save it along with the respective answers array. Like this, please let me know if i m missing anything or also if you have any comment on doing it in a better way.

Comment: var questions = JSON.parse(req.body.questions); 
    for (i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
         new questionModel({
        questionType:questions[i].questionType,
        questionText:questions[i].questionText,
        answers:questions[i].answers
      }).save();
     }

Comment: Happy to help! I think your solution sounds reasonable. Happy coding!